# Increasing load and hold time on a stress testing

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am conducting a stress testing for a web application. I have test scenario where I am testing functionality such as homepage , login and product catalogue and I am using a ultimate thread group. So I am increasing load for example with 100 user , initial delay 5 sec, startup time 50sec, hold time 3600sec and shut down time 50 sec. Is this a realistic stress test? And what matrices should I look and how should I examine them to make a decision? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really look like a stress test to me, it's rather a [load test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing) or a [soak test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Soak_testing) if you want.

- With regards to "realistic" - we don't know what you're trying to achieve.

  If you expect that the application will be used by 100 users then the test is realistic (as long as you [configured JMeter to act like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) and use [think-times](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-with-a-think-time))
- With regards to `matrices` - we don't know again, if you're running a load or a soak test most probably you need to know whether your application performance is acceptable when it's being used by 100 users, so you should have some form of acceptance criteria like [non-functional requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) or [SLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement), example criteria:

  - response time must not be higher than X milliseconds
  - application throughput should be not lower than Y transactions per second
  - number of errors should not be higher than Z % of total requests
  - etc.

JMeter's [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) should give you the answers to the majority of questions

If you're new to the concept of web applications performance testing I would recommend getting familiarized with [Performance Testing Guidance for Web Applications](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=perftestingguide) book prior to start coding and running.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thanks for your answer! Actually I want to do a stress test. Because the application I am testing does not have any non-functional requirement or SLA . So That is why I want to conduct a stress test first and determine how many users it can handle until it breaks or get inconsistent with the performance. Can please suggest me how should design the stress test in terms loading users and holding time? Thanks again.